# Prove $Tf$ is continuous, $T$ is a contraction and find a solution to the integral $f(x)$

Tags: continuity, banach-spaces

On the Banach space $(C([0,1]), ||.||_\infty)$, consider the operator given by
$$(Tf)(x)=\int_0^1 x^2tf(t) dt+1.$$

a.) Prove that $Tf$ is continuous for all $f\in C([0,1])$.

b.) Show that $T$ is a contraction mapping.

c.) Let $f_n(x)=\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}\right)x^2+1$,
where $n\geq 1$. What is the solution of $$f(x)=\int_0^1 x^2tf(x) dt +1?$$

For a.) I say that we need to show that $T$ maps $(C([0,1]), ||.||_\infty)$ to itself.

So, $x\longrightarrow 1$ is constant and enables us to write,

$$|1|.\left|\int_0^1x^2tf(t)dt-\int_0^1x'^2tf(t)dt\right|=|x^2-x'^2|.\left|\int_0^1tf(t)dt\right|.$$

However, I think that instead of saying $|x^2-x'^2|$, we should say $|x^2|$? Is this correct? And then as $f$ is continuous, $tf(t)$ is continuous and integrable and so $Tf$ is continuous.

b.) To show $T$ is a contraction, we say
$$\left|Tf(x)-Tg(x)\right| = \left|\left|x^2\int_0^1t(f(t)-g(t))\right|\right|_\infty\leq ||f-g||_\infty.$$

I am uncertain if I am missing a coefficient in front of $||f-g||_\infty$?

I would then say that $||Tf-Tg||_\infty\leq ||f-g||_\infty$.

Lastly, for c.), I think we should use Banach's fixed point theorem? And this would allow us to say $f(x)=?$ Or use Picard iteration?

Please let me know if you notice any flaws and help me rectify them.

Thank you

Comment: Unless there is a typo, note your function maps a function $f$ to $K(f)x^2+1$ where $K$ is the functional that maps $f$ to $\int_0^1 tf(t)dt$.

Comment: @ Luis_G:  I am having a hard time seeing how the sequence $f_n(x)$ defined in part (c) of your question relates to the solution of $f(x) = \int_0^1 x^2 t f(x) dt + 1$; also, is the occurrance of $f(x)$ under the integral sign correct?  Or should it perhaps be $f(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**
Note that
$$
(Tf)(x) = \left(\int_0^1 tf(t)\,dt \right)x^2 + 1
$$
For b), note that
$$
\left|Tf(x)-Tg(x)\right| = \left\|x^2\int_0^1t(f(t)-g(t))dt\right\|_\infty\leq 
\left\| x^2 \int_0^1 t(\|f-g\|_\infty)\,dt
\right\|_\infty = \cdots ?
$$

For c): in order to find a fixed point, solve the equation
$$
\int_0^1 t(at^2 + 1)\,dt = a
$$
for $a$.  Use some theorem to show that the corresponding fixed point is unique.

Comment: How would I go about solving this equation? And is my answer to a.) correct? I think I have included some errors in my proof?

Comment: I think your answer to a) is fine, if perhaps overly elaborate.  Note that we can just write
$$
(Tf)(x) = \left(\int_0^1 tf(t)\,dt \right)x^2 + 1
$$
Which is a polynomial and therefore continuous

Comment: To solve the equation, first integrate with respect to $t$, noting that $a$ is simply a constant.